# unable to upload files widthout database entry

Tags: php

I am trying to upload images to a folder without database entry I found this code on google but I am continuously getting an error on this I don't know what I am doing wrong with this code.

HTML:

```
<div class="upload-btn-container">
    <button class="btn bg-red btn-block btn-lg waves-effect">Passport/EID</button>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" class="btn-fake-upload" />
</div>
<div class="upload-btn-container">
    <button class="btn bg-red btn-block btn-lg waves-effect">Visa</button>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" class="btn-fake-upload" />
</div>
<div class="upload-btn-container">
    <button class="btn bg-red btn-block btn-lg waves-effect">Licence</button>
     <input type="file" name="files[]" class="btn-fake-upload" />
</div>
<div class="upload-btn-container">
     <button class="btn bg-red btn-block btn-lg waves-effect">Credit Card</button>
     <input type="file" name="files[]" class="btn-fake-upload" />
</div>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-addcust'])) {
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg", "pdf");
$max_file_size = 1024*1000; //1000 kb
$path = "../"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;
// Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue; // Skip file if any error found
    }          
    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
        if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
            continue; // Skip large files
        }
        elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
            $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        }
        else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
            $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
        }
    }
}
}
```

Error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: files in F:\xampp\htdocs\erp\include\addcust.php on line 33
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in F:\xampp\htdocs\erp\include\addcust.php on line 33
```

any help or explanation which helps to understand will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with PDO?

Comment: Does the form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: Does your form contain enctype="multipart/form-data"? The errors you are getting is because the array $_FILES doesn't have a key 'files'. Make sure the file is getting posted correctly. Also, add a if condition on top of your foreach loop. if(!empty($_FILES['files']){} else { echo "no files selected"; }

Comment: @Mir Thanks for the answer now files are uploading I found a problem in my code.